# How to convert a list inside of a list from json in dart

Tags: dart

Imagine you have the following json

```
{
  "list": [
    ["xa", "yc", "ze"],
    ["xb", "yd", "zf"]
  ]
}
```

how do we convert this to a `List<List<String>>` with `json.decode()` in dart?

Comment: Just use this tool https://quicktype.io

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make the assumption that this is a string before you pass it to `jsonDecode`, which will return a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

```dart
// The original string
String jsonString = "{\"list\": [[\"xa\", \"yc\", \"ze\"], [\"xb\", \"yd\", \"zf\"]]}";

// The parsed map
Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
```

Now, it seems like you don't care about the containing `Map`.
Technically, those things that look like `List`s are actually `Map`s at this point, so those type assertions would fail.

```dart
List<List<String>> output = json["list"].map((value) => value.toList()).toList();
```

That's the most straightforward method I can think of right now.